# Calculating Std. Dev. of a numpy array if, skipping rows where a condition is met

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

First time poster here!

Say I have a 3D numpy array (2, 6, 3) that looks like this(pseudo-code):

```
 matrix = [[['1' 'blue' '0.767041']
      ['2' 'yellow' '0.647259']
      ['3' 'green' '0.990185']
      ['4' 'red' '0.593180']
      ['5' 'green' '0.855915']
      ['6' 'blue' '1.335018']]  
     [['1' 'blue' '0.767041']
          ['2' 'yellow' '0.647259']
          ['3' 'green' '0.990185']
          ['4' 'red' '0.593180']
          ['5' 'green' '0.855915']
          ['6' 'blue' '1.335018']]]
```

How would I use go about calculating statistics, for example the std. dev. of the 3rd column for each 2D array, on the condition that the 2nd column == "blue"?

This is what I've tried(pseudo-code):

```
stddev_blue = []
for pts in matrix:
    if pts[:, 1] == "blue":
            stddev_blue.append(np.std(pts[:, 2].astype(float)))
```

But I keep getting the error `"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"`. I've done some research on these two functions, but I can't quite understand how to apply them to my problem!

Could anyone give me some direction here?

Full disclosure - this is part of an assignment.

Thanks!

Comment: How about `np.std(matrix[:,:,2].astype(float), axis=0)`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - would that confine the calculation to only the trials where "blue" is present? Unless I'm missing something!

Comment: You shouldn't be using `numpy` if you are just going to put strings in your array... that removes all the advantages (speed and memory efficiency) of `numpy`.

Comment: Any and all test whether at least one or all of the elements of an array evaluate as true

Comment: I guess something like this : `np.std(matrix[matrix[...,1] == 'blue',2].astype(float))`? That would produce one scalar though.

Comment: To complete answer of qwr : you are getting the error message because pts[:, 1] == "blue" is an array of boolean values with same shape as pts[:, 1] and that the truth of such an array is ambiguous, so the message suggest you to convert this array into a scalar with numpy.any or numpy.all but this is not what you need here.